# Composite C1 CMS - Beginner video tutorial

Tags: c1-cms

I'm looking for a beginner level video tutorial to get me up to the level where I can create a CMS site.

I have found a lot of individual snippets - but nothing that guides you through the whole thing.

An equivalent in web or PDF would be a good second choice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. ["Getting Started" Guide: Installation, Setup, Adding a blog, Adding a gallery, Customizing the design, Getting the website online](http://docs.composite.net/Getting-started/Guide)
2. http://users.composite.net/User-Guide/User-Guide
3. http://users.composite.net/Getting-Started (Videos for beginners)

Answer (score 1):

I too have faced such a problem 1 month back when I first went through Composite c1.
Please check my blog.
http://vishnunadesh.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/getting-started/

I think you have already passed through these pages .

Steps are like this.
First study of installation its simple installation as given in composite then

Then go through creation of page.This can be done by creating page template and page type.
then create a page with this page type. All are listed in starter video.

Then on moving to coding you can find creation of user control, installation of new packages and all